# How to get records from ms-access for specific date (Excluding time) by writing qyeury in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to fetch the records from MS-Access table by writing query in vb.net windows application.

Table have below data in DateTime Column.

```
    12/10/2016  12:50:25 PM
    12/11/2016  12:50:29 PM
    12/14/2016  12:50:29 PM
    12/13/2016  12:49:29 PM
    12/13/2016  12:51:29 PM
    12/13/2016  12:51:55 PM
```

When I write the below query in vb.net ,I get the zero records.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CDATE(INT(CreatedDate)) = #12/13/2016#
```

How to get the recordsonly through date, excluding time ?

Comment: It should work with `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE INT(CreatedDate) = #12/13/2016#`.

Comment: I have tried it, its not wrking, If I put > sign `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE INT(CreatedDate) >= #12/13/2016#` then it works... so I have to make change in query...

Comment: Then something else is going on. `INT(CreatedDate) = #12/13/2016#` _will_ return three records. Perhaps you are using _DateTime2_ and an old _SQL Server_ driver. If so, either change to _DateTime_ or use the newer native SQL Server driver version 10 or 11.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
Dim date = Date.Today
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CreatedDate >= @StartDate AND CreatedDate < @EndDate", connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@StartDate", date)
    .Add("@EndDate", date.AddDays(1))
End With
```

You may also be able to use the BETWEEN operator but I can never remember whether the limits are inclusive or exclusive.

EDIT:

While any system that requires you to build SQL using text is a bad system, requirements are requirements.  That said, the principle is still exactly the same and anyone who can't use a demonstrated principle in their own code is in trouble from the get-go.  Anyway, here's how you can do it without using parameters:

```
Dim date = Date.Today
Dim sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CreatedDate >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND CreatedDate < #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#",
                        date,
                        date.AddDays(1))
```

As you can see, the principle is EXACTLY the same and all that changes is how you get the dates into the SQL.

Comment: They are inclusive.

Comment: @bnil re: "cant use command parameters" - Edit your question to explain why.

Comment: I am using objects of DB Classes... SQL command not accessible to me...  I can send only text formatted query...

Comment: Maybe you should consider providing all the relevant information in the first place, to avoid people wasting their time with inappropriate answers. We can't read your mind so if you can't do what should be done then tell us.  I will edit my answer to what I would have provided in the first place had you not kept your requirements secret.